# Wordpress theme: Display Only One Category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress theme, displays all of the categories a post is in on the homepage, I only want to display one category even if a post is under multiple categories.

This is the code in my theme:

```
function metro_magazine_colored_category(){
$output = '';
// Hide category for pages.
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {     
    $categories_list = get_the_category();
    if ( $categories_list ) {
      $output .= '<div class="category-holder">';
            foreach( $categories_list as $category ){
            $color_code = get_theme_mod( 'metro_magazine_category_color_' . $category->term_id );
                if ( $color_code ) {
                   $output .= '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" style="background:' . esc_attr( $color_code ) . '" rel="category tag">'. esc_html( $category->cat_name ) .'</a>';
                }else{
                   $output .= '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '"  rel="category tag">' . esc_html( $category->cat_name ) . '</a>';
                }
            }
        $output .= '</div>';
        echo $output;         
    }
}e

} 
endif;
```

[This is the form that can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG07d.png)

Comment: Do you need to show only the first category only?

Comment: Yes, the first one is OK.

Comment: Please check the answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code may help you. You dont need the foreach loop as you are expecting to print only the first category only. Hope it helps.

```
function metro_magazine_colored_category(){
  $output = '';
  // Hide category for pages.
  if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {     
      $categories_list = get_the_category();
      if ( $categories_list ) {
        $output .= '<div class="category-holder">';
              $color_code = get_theme_mod( 'metro_magazine_category_color_' . $categories_list[0]->term_id );
                  if ( $color_code ) {
                     $output .= '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) ) . '" style="background:' . esc_attr( $color_code ) . '" rel="category tag">'. esc_html( $categories_list[0]->cat_name ) .'</a>';
                  }else{
                     $output .= '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories_list[0]->term_id ) ) . '"  rel="category tag">' . esc_html( $categories_list[0]->cat_name ) . '</a>';
                  }
          $output .= '</div>';
          echo $output;         
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tristup, but it's not showing any category now

Comment: Ok, I am checking it.